# Can't access root_url method when building a PDF file offline using WickedPdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

We use WickedPdf, a wkhtmltopdf wrapper, for generating most of our PDF files on-screen as we can use the same .haml file for both HTML and PDF versions.

I'd like to generate some of the PDF files to be stored for future use. We already do something like this in a mailer to generate and attach a PDF. This works fine...

```
# mailer
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string('account/customer_invoices/show_pdf.html', :layout => 'pdf'))
attachments["invoice.pdf"] = pdf
```

But when I try the same trick from within a model instead of a mailer, I get the following error...

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `root_url' for #<#<Class:0x007fad308a8538>:0x007fad308a83d0>
```

The standard answer I've seen for accessing the root_url from within a model is to add the following, but it doesn't work as I'm actually accessing it from the view, not the model.

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you call `root_url` in the view.

Try changing that to

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url
```